# Question over images and subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $f$ be an isomorphism from group $G$ to group $H$. Suppose $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Prove that the image of $K$ under $f$, the set of all elements $f(k)$ as $k$ ranges over $K$, is a normal subgroup of $H$

Answer (score 1):

Since $K$ is normal, we have that $gK = Kg$, for all $g \in G$. By isomorphism, $f(gK) = f(g)f(K) = f(Kg) = f(K)f(g)$. By surjectivity of the isomorphism, we have that for all $h \in H$, $\exists{g} \in G$ such that $f(g) = h$. Thus, we have for all $h \in H$, $f(g)f(K) = f(K)f(g)$. So $f(K) \triangleleft H$.